# Haskell GADTs - making a type-safe Tensor types for Riemannian geometry

Tags: haskell, type-safety, gadt, data-kinds

I want to make a type safe implementation of Tensor calculus in Haskell using GADT's, so the rules are:

1. Tensors are n-dimentional metrices with indecies that can be 'upstairs' or 'downstairs' eg: [image] - is a Tensor with no indecies (a scalar), [image] is a Tensor with one 'upstairs' index, [image] is a tensor with a bunch of 'upstairs' and 'downstairs' indecies
2. You can ADD tensor of the same type, meaning they have the same indecies signature. the 0th index of the first tensor is of the same type(upstairs or downstairs) as the 0th index of the second tensor and so on...

   [image]  ~~~~ OK

   [image]  ~~~~ NOT OK
3. You can MULTIPLY tensors and get bigger tensors, with the indecies concatenated: [image]

So I want that the type-checker of Haskell wouldn't allow me to write code that doesn't follow those rules, It wouldn't compile otherwise.

Here is my attempt using GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data Direction = T | X | Y | Z
data Index = Zero | Up Index | Down Index deriving (Eq, Show)

plus :: Index -> Index -> Index
plus Zero x = x
plus (Up x) y = Up (plus x y)
plus (Down x) y = Down (plus x y)

data Tensor a = (a ~ Zero) => Scalar Double | 
                forall b. (a ~ Up b) => Cov (Direction -> Tensor b) |
                forall b. (a ~ Down b) => Con (Direction -> Tensor b) 

add :: Tensor a -> Tensor a -> Tensor a
add (Scalar x) (Scalar y) = (Scalar (x + y))
add (Cov f) (Cov g) = (Cov (\d -> add (f d) (g d)))
add (Con f) (Con g) = (Con (\d -> add (f d) (g d)))

mul :: Tensor a -> Tensor b -> Tensor (plus a b)
mul (Scalar x) (Scalar y) = (Scalar (x*y))
mul (Scalar x) (Cov f) = (Cov (\d -> mul (Scalar x) (f d)))
mul (Scalar x) (Con f) = (Con (\d -> mul (Scalar x) (f d)))
mul (Cov f) y = (Cov (\d -> mul (f d) y))
mul (Con f) y = (Con (\d -> mul (f d) y))
```

But i'm getting:

```
Couldn't match type 'Down with `plus ('Down b1)'                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Expected type: Tensor (plus a b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      Actual type: Tensor ('Down b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    Relevant bindings include                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      f :: Direction -> Tensor b1 (bound at main.hs:28:10)                                                                                                                                                                                              
      mul :: Tensor a -> Tensor b -> Tensor (plus a b)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        (bound at main.hs:24:1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    In the expression: (Con (\ d -> mul (f d) y))                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    In an equation for `mul':                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        mul (Con f) y = (Con (\ d -> mul (f d) y))
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You wrote `plus` as a (value level) function but you're trying to use it in a type. Haskell can't do that. (It thinks the `plus` in the return type of `mul` is a type parameter.) Use type families.

Comment: I used type-operators

Comment: May I recommend you also consider [a coordinate-free approach to tensors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.2.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html), without those silly indices...

Comment: @leftaroundabout wow cool library.  Not just an abstract model, but also some workhorses -- inversion, eigenvalues, ... .  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I actually like the index notation. Maybe It's just a bias, I learned general relativity in this notation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plus` is just a function on values of type `Index`

```
>>> plus Zero Zero
Zero
>>> plus Zero (Up Zero)
Up Zero
```

so it can't appear in a type signature, as things are. You want to use the 'promoted' type where `Zero`, `Up Zero` etc. are types. Then you can write a type function and everything compiles.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Direction = T | X | Y | Z
data Index = Zero | Up Index | Down Index deriving (Eq, Show)

-- type function Plus
type family Plus (i :: Index) (j :: Index) :: Index where
  Plus Zero x = x
  Plus (Up x) y  = Up (Plus x y)
  Plus (Down x) y = Down (Plus x y)

-- value fuction plus
plus :: Index -> Index -> Index
plus Zero x = x
plus (Up x) y = Up (plus x y)
plus (Down x) y = Down (plus x y)

data Tensor (a :: Index) where
  Scalar :: Double -> Tensor Zero
  Cov :: (Direction -> Tensor b) -> Tensor (Up b)
  Con :: (Direction -> Tensor b) -> Tensor (Down b)

add :: Tensor a -> Tensor a -> Tensor a
add (Scalar x) (Scalar y) = (Scalar (x + y))
add (Cov f) (Cov g) = (Cov (\d -> add (f d) (g d)))
add (Con f) (Con g) = (Con (\d -> add (f d) (g d)))

mul :: Tensor a -> Tensor b -> Tensor (Plus a b)
mul (Scalar x) (Scalar y) = (Scalar (x*y))
mul (Scalar x) (Cov f) = (Cov (\d -> mul (Scalar x) (f d)))
mul (Scalar x) (Con f) = (Con (\d -> mul (Scalar x) (f d)))
mul (Cov f) y = (Cov (\d -> mul (f d) y))
mul (Con f) y = (Con (\d -> mul (f d) y))
```

There was no ambiguity in `Plus` but I could have use the disambiguating tick `'` to signal that I was dealing with the type level `Zero`, `Up` etc.

```
type family Plus (i :: Index) (j :: Index) :: Index where
  Plus 'Zero x = x
  Plus ('Up x) y  = 'Up (Plus x y)
  Plus ('Down x) y = 'Down (Plus x y)
```

`TypeOperators` would permit you to write `a + b` rather than `Plus a b` above.

```
type family (i :: Index) + (j :: Index) :: Index where
  Zero + x = x
  Up x + y  = Up (x + y)
  Down x + y = Down (x + y)
```